# Migration of public folders from Exchange 2010 to Icewarp

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-migration, public-folders

We are in the process of Migrating Exchange 2010 to Icewarp.
The migration process works without problems for postboxes and items. I'm feeling absolutely lost when it comes to Exchange public folders.

There is NO document about that, even though there is a Manual about the migration it does (nearly) not cover the public folders.

In the migration App there are those settings. Does anybody have an idea what to fill in there?

What is the "Exchange source mailbox" of a public folder?
I have no idea how to use on this stuff.
[image]

I'm thinking about exporting the content of those Exchange Public folders via Outlook into a pst-file and then import it (somehow?) into Icewarp public folders.

Comment: All public folders we are using in Exchange are created by an Administrator as "Public default folders" in EMC. 
When i select Administrator@mydom.com as "Exchange Source Mailbox" or any other Account, the migration throws an error "Unable to explore folder tree, because The Id property must be set." and just did not stop any more with the migration till i abort the migration run.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, "Public folders stay behind other account data in MS Exchange. There is no exact one-to-one correspondence between MS
Exchange and IceWarp server, thus public folders are created under a group with the Group name specified here.If the Migrate through this account (mandatory) box is not checked, public folders will not be migrated" which is mentioned in this [article](http://dl.icewarp.com/documentation/server/tools/Exchange_Migrator_Guide.pdf). And did you use IceWarp Exchange migrator to migrate exchange server,if yes, you also could refer to above article.

In addition, Could you fill out the master migration account as exchange source mailbox? For accurate replies, you'd better to seek for an expert on Icewarp.

Comment: yeah, i read that also. And i read that only because it's the only doc i could find about that issue.
I think Icewarp is fine, but documentation and support could be MUCH better. There own forum is a joke :-(